# Make a general dashboard for multiple properties in the same page

Tags: google-analytics

I have 3 websites (or sometimes more) that I manage with Google Analytics, i.e. I have 3 "properties":

[image]

How can I generate a **custom dashboard that displays pageviews graphs for each of the 3 sites on a single page?**

Something like this:

[image]

When I tried to use the **customisation feature**, all I achieved to do is a custom dashboard but for a **specific property**:

[image]

**How to do a custom dashboard that can display data from multiple properties / multiple websites?** (to give the big picture of the traffic for multiple websites in a single shot)

Comment: May not be exactly what you were looking for since it's not in Google Analytics per se, but you can use Data Studio for this purpose: https://datastudio.google.com

Comment: I second @cjl750's suggestion , especially since you cannot create a dashboard for multiple properties in GA directly. Apart from Data Studio you can use a combination of Google Apps Scripts and Google Spreadsheets (which is basically what Data Studio is built upon) if you need to do advanced calculations or combine data from the various properties.

Comment: @EikePierstorff ok this is useful information (part of an answer actually) : is it 100% sure it's *"impossible to create a dashboard for multiple properties in GA directly"*? I thought that it could be possible and that I maybe missed one feature somewhere in GA. If you do know how to do this, could you explain in a few steps how to do this with DataStudio?

Comment: Dashboards are view-based in Google Analytics. So not only you can't create dashboards for multiple properties, you cannot even create a single dashboard that includes different views. Data studio however allows you to add each view as different data source - however you cannot combine data from different data sources into one table widget, for that you'd need an API based solution like the mentioned Google Spreadsheet (or software like Tableau, or services like megalytic.com (not affiliated) or similiar).

Comment: @EikePierstorff "however you cannot combine data from different data sources into one table widget" : is it possible to combine data from different properties on a single page [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs9cE.png) using multiple widgets, with DataStudio? "Like the mentioned Google Spreadsheet" : which spreadsheet was mentioned? (maybe it is in a deleted comment?)

Comment: Btw. if that was not clear, by "in GA directly" I mean within the Google Analytics user interface.

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple data sources (GA views, Adwords Accounts, Mysql Tables, Google Spreadsheets and others) on the same page in Data Studio, so for your use case this should work fine. You just cannot aggregate data from different source.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, dashboards sit on the "view" level, along with custom reports. With that in mind, here are 2 ways I can imagine accomplishing the goal of "I want to see all my data from all the websites I'm tracking in one dashboard."

1. Use Data Studio. This kind of thing is pretty much exactly what it was designed for -- you can blend data from all your GA properties into a single data source and build reports off of it.
2. If you *must* have your dashboard inside Google Analytics, you could shift your account structure down one level. Instead of 1 account, 3 properties, you could create 1 account, 1 property, and send all the data to the same GA tracking code. Then, you use different views to segment your websites' data--and one of those views will include all the data from all the sites. The others will be filtered (probably by hostname, but you can do it a number of ways.)

For example, this property would have an "All data" view, a "Website A" view, "Website B" view, etc.

Comment: Thank you! Wish I would have known what Data Studio can do sooner!